# is there a way to revert a changeset in visual studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, tfs

Is there a way to revert changes for a particular changeset in visual studio 2005 and tfs/2005?

Thanks,
rod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to use the team foundation power tools rollback command to do it

TFPT: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7324c3db-658d-441b-8522-689c557d0a79&displaylang=en

How to rollback: http://vstsguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20undo%20a%20check-in